# Nodejs: MySQL package seems to freeze after a short burt of queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, asynchronous, backend, es6-promise

To preface, I've only been using Javascript and SQL for about a week so please point out any poor form you see here.

I'm writing an express server which needs to combine the results of multiple SQL queries into a single object. This uses the the mysql node plugin. I've got the following:

```
const db = require('./db.js');
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM departments';
db.query(sql, async function(err, dptrows){
  let departments = dptrows.map( d => d);

  for (let dindex = 0; dindex < departments.length; dindex++) {

    sql = 'SELECT * FROM dpt'+dindex+'itemtypes';

    console.log(sql);

    let curQuery = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, (err, typerows) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          resolve(typerows);
        }
      });
    }).catch(err => {});

    let typerows = await curQuery || [];
    departments[dindex].itemTypes = typerows;
    console.log(typerows);
  }

  console.log(departments);
});
```

And below is the imported db.js. A lot of this file is, admittedly, cargo code.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host : process.env.DB_HOST,
  user : process.env.DB_USER,
  password : process.env.DB_PASS,
  database : process.env.DB_DB,
  connnectionLimit:50,
  supportBigNumbers: true
});

exports.query = function(sql, data, callback) {

  pool.getConnection( function(err, connection) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback(true);
      return;
    }

    connection.query(sql, data, function(err, results) {
      connection.release();

      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(true);
        return;
      }

      callback(false, results);
    });
  });
};
```

When this runs, it spits out the following:

```
SELECT * FROM dpt0itemtypes
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    name: 'placeholder item'
  }
]
SELECT * FROM dpt1itemtypes
[]
SELECT * FROM dpt2itemtypes
[]
SELECT * FROM dpt3itemtypes
[]
SELECT * FROM dpt4itemtypes
```

It freezes here. The output right up to that final SELECT statement is completely expected; blank arrays come back from each query after the first because dpt1itemtypes and so forth are tables that I haven't made yet. But why does it freeze on dpt4itemtypes? The promise on this query is never fulfilled or rejected, and there are still two more queries to make.

Is this an error in the configuration of my mysql pool object? Perhaps an error in the configuration of my MySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is actually pretty embarrassing.

mysql.query can take either two arguments or three, but my db.js wrapper only invokes the form that takes three arguments. It's not set up to handle any invocations of the two argument query method, so my first block of code above was passing a callback function to a function which expects some kind of array. Bad stuff ensues.